# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver

Tags: java, jdbc, firebird, jaybird

I am not able to access the Firebird configuration string, and it works perfectly in MySQL.

```
package testej;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class TesteConexao {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            
            Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");
            String URL = "jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:C:/DB/DASHBOARD.FDB";
            String usuario = "SYSDBA";
            String senha = "masterkey";
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, usuario, senha);
            System.out.println("Conexão efetuada com sucesso!");
            conn.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            
            ex.printStackTrace();
            
        }

    }

}
```

java version "1.8.0_311", my firebird is 3.0.10 33601 x64, jdbc driver jaybird4.0.8 1.8 ,jaybird 3.0.12 1.8 , jaxb.2.3.0

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
    at testej.TesteConexao.main(TesteConexao.java:12)
```

Comment: Please show how you're running your program, specifically how you have configured the classpath. The error means that the Jaybird JDBC driver is not on the classpath. As an aside, the stacktrace shows you're using Java 9 or higher to run, not Java 8. Also, please translate the sentence before the stacktrace. It seems to be Portuguese. If I interpret that correctly, you seem to be trying and Jaybird 4.0.8 *and* Jaybird 3.0.12. You should pick only one.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that Jaybird is not on the classpath. When running your application, make sure you specify the correct classpath (you need both `jaybird-4.0.8.java8.jar` and `connector-api-1.5.jar`):

For example:

```
java -cp .;D:\libs\jaybird-4.0.8.java8\jaybird-4.0.8.java8.jar;D:\libs\jaybird-4.0.8.java8\lib\connector-api-1.5.jar testej.TesteConexao
```

or (only) `jaybird-full-4.0.8.java8.jar`:

```
java -cp .;D:\libs\jaybird-4.0.8.java8\jaybird-full-4.0.8.java8.jar testej.TesteConexao
```

When running from Linux, use `:` as the classpath separator instead of `;`.

As an aside, explicitly loading the driver with `Class.forName` hasn't been necessary since Jaybird 2.2 on Java 6 or higher.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem was that I had not unzipped the jaybird lib, so I unzipped it and added it to the project, everything went well.